# create cairo context without a present window object

Tags: c++, cairo

I am currently using libcairomm for graphic stuff in my program.

All the internet examples use code like

```
Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> cr = window->create_cairo_context();
```

But I am using cairo to pass a svg texture to OpenGL
 Is there a kind of constructor working without that window ?

Thank you for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont't understand quite. The cairomm docs have working examples which show how to create all kinds of of non-windowed surfaces:

http://cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/examples.html

You can also allocate your own memory and pass it to create an image surface:

http://cairographics.org/documentation/cairomm/reference/classCairo_1_1ImageSurface.html#feb1b8203f9fa23ff4bca7b70723f370

This might be helpful if you want to prepare some texture for OpenGL.